# How many request can handle web.py?

Tags: python, web.py, tile

I have a question regarding processing tiles. I have tiles with the size of 500m. The Client is sending request to the webserver (web.py) to get these tiles. Of course if I decrease the tile size (e. g. 200m) then the performance of the tile is faster (because of lower size).

The client can send any requests to the webserver. My question is how many requests can handle web.py?

Comment: Do you mean parallel requests (received at the same time)? Also clarify what you mean `tiles with the size of 500m`?

Comment: Also, are use using default web.py webserver (bad idea, for production), or is it being served by nginx (good idea). Your webserver can run many processes and threads greatly improving throughput.

Answer (score 1):

The default web.py web server only handles maximum 10 concurrent requests which is not for production use.
You can edit the web.py source code and change this which is **NOT** recommended. Refer [this](https://github.com/webpy/webpy/issues/358).

For production use you have to use FastCGI with lighttpd.

web.py documentation says,

> FastCGI with lighttpd is the recommended way of using web.py in
>   production. reddit.com handles millions of hits this way.

Refer [this](http://webpy.org/install).

Comment: Ah ok good to hear. So I am using the default web server. Now I have to change it to FastCGI with lighthttpd.  This can handle more requeste then 10 right?

Comment: Yes, But they have less documentation. So I hosted in apache. You can also do it in IIS.

Comment: Ok at the moment I am using IIS with web.py. So for production use I have to change the Interface to FastCGI? And this will solve my problem?

Comment: I have no clear idea about that. But refer this http://webpy.org/cookbook/iis7_iis6_windows_pyisapie

Comment: Do you have a source where this information that the default web.py webserver can handle maximum 10 requests?

Comment: I also had that issue for weeks. But only source I could come up was the git hub link I attached in the answer. One of the main contributor to web.py named anandology also commented there. But when I go through the code it was true.